# How to remove an element inside a div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Um trying to remove an HTML element by JQuery as follows

```
$('#' + divId + ' .settings_class').remove('.print_settings');
```

This does not throw an error or remove the html element.
but the selector correctly retrieves the element.

```
$('#' + divId + ' .settings_class .print_settings');
```

How to remove an element inside a div by its class as follows?

Comment: `$('#' + divId + ' .settings_class .print_settings').remove();` will remove.

Comment: Alternatively, using the selector syntax: `$('#' + divId + ' .settings_class div').remove('.print_settings');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#' + divId + ' .settings_class').find('.print_settings').remove();
```

Comment: this didnt remove the elelent

Comment: @Kalanamith: Your syntax is perfectly valid. You have to just specify *what* elements of class `.print_settings`: `$('#' + divId + ' .settings_class div').remove('.print_settings');`, assuming your elements are `div`s.

Answer (score 1):

If `$('#' + divId + ' .settings_class .print_settings');` retriving correct element then use `remove()` on it! like

`$('#' + divId + ' .settings_class .print_settings').remove();`